# Distinguish the end-entity cert in a PKCS#7 (P7B) cert chain

Tags: certificates, pkcs7

Is there a standard/definitive way to distinguish the end-entity cert in a PKCS#7 (P7B) cert chain?  I believe the PKCS#7 standard doesn't not specify sequence when ordering the certs in the chain, but most tools do sequence them in (either bkw or fwd) signing order).  And I know an end cert would have different owner/issuer CNs (root's would be the same for both), was wondering if there was a foolproof differentiator say, in the case of an end and intermediate cert, where both would have different owner/issuer (right?).  Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CA certificates (V3) always include `Basic Constraints` certificate extension where `isCA` attribute is set to `True`. End-entity certificates either, omit this extension or include extension with `isCA` attribute set to `False`. Basic Constraints ([RFC 5280 §4.2.1.9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9)) is the most reliable way to differentiate CA and end entity certificates.

Here is an example of Basic Constraints extension for CA certificate in Windows Certificate Viewer:

[image]

an example of Basic Constraints extension for end entity certificate in Windows Certificate Viewer:
[image]

Comment: Ah, "Basic Constraints" is an X.509v3 extension.  And I see I can get at this ext from .Net too; nice, thx!  Hmm; what would an intermediate CA signer look like?  BTW I assume u meant "...extension for end-entity certificate..." in ur 2nd example.

Comment: Intermediate CA signer is CA.

Comment: Got it.  Also friendly reminder to update 2nd example text to reflect "end entity".

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer. It was a copy/paste issue.